# Authenticated routes that can not be modified with the redux developer tools chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have made an authorized route with a HOC component, but this has a problem.

The user can change the store with the **redux** and **react** developer tools chrome extension and this can cause security lacks.

The user can change in this developer tools chrome the permission "PERMISSION" to another word and modify the status of the application.

Could you do this so that the user can not change the store?

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (   
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
              <AuthorizedComponent path="/administration" authed={true} permissions={["PERMISSION"]} component={AdministrationPage} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

AuthorizedComponent.js

```
class AuthorizedComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { user } = this.props;
        const  WrappedComponent  = this.props.component;

        if (user && user.authToken && user.permissions === "PERMISSION") {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
        }else if (user && user.authToken && !this.accessControl.hasPermission) {
            return <AccessDeniedComponent></AccessDeniedComponent>
        } else {
            return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: this.props.location } }} />;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For disabling react dev tools:**

in your `index.html` add following `script`:

```
<script>
    window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.inject = function () {}
</script>
```

---

**For disabling redux dev tools:**

When you're creating your store object, you did something like:

```
const store = createStore(reducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(), applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

Use `process` environment variable to change it for production so the user couldn't manipulate data in redux developer tools.

You gotta do something like:

```
let store = null
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") 
    store = createStore(reducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(), applyMiddleware(thunk))
else 
    store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

And remember for security it's better to call a request to server to see if user has permission.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is perfect for the redux developer tools of the chrome extension, but I have the same problem with the chrome extension reactivity developer tools.
In the Chrome reactivity developer tools. The user can change authed to <AuthorizedComponent path="/administration" authed={true} permissions={["PERMISSION"]} component={AdministrationPage} />  and modify the state of the application.

Do you have any idea for this? Thank you very much again.

Comment: Thanks. Is your answer correct to deactivate redux and react developer tools?

Comment: I did test and use both of them.

Comment: You have made my day! Your solution is what I need. Now I only have one ploblem, I want to show REACT_DEVTOOLS in development but not in production and with <script>
    window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.inject = function () {}
</script>, I deactivate in both. Any idea?

Comment: You could try something like `if(window.location.hostname !== 'localhost') window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.inject = function () {}`